# When I `throw` something, where is it stored in memory?

Tags: c++, exception

I understand that when something is `throw`n, the stack is 'unwound' to the point where it is caught, and the destructors of class instances on the stack in each function context are run (which is why you should not throw an exception from a destructor - you could end up throwing a second one)...but I wonder where in memory the object that I have thrown is stored while this happens?

Is it implementation dependent? If so, is there a particular method used by most popular compilers?

Comment: Good question - it's probably not specified by the standard, since the standard doesn't even say that you have to have a stack. Practically, perhaps it's allocated on the heap and freed when the catch block exits?

Comment: @Kerrek: I think more likely, the object is placed on the stack way down at the "bottom". Then unwind upwards, remembering where it was, and once you've finished unwinding (including giving any catch clauses the opportunity to address the exception by reference, and to re-`raise` it), destroy it. The issue with heap allocation is, what do you do if your attempt to allocate the exception fails? You'd have to abort (just as you would for stack overflow if putting it on the stack "fails" due to lack of space). Unlike Java the implementation isn't allowed to throw a different exception instead.

Comment: @Steve: Also possible - Kiril's article says that the exception is allocated on the stack, and an auxiliary info structure records its address and deleter etc., but I imagine that implementations are free to do this in any way they like?

Comment: @Kerrek: yes, subject to the constraint that it has to actually throw the exception, and the usual issue that running out of stack permits the implementation to evade such responsibilities :-) If you put it on the stack, then because exceptions are thrown by the *static* type of the throw expression, your stack frame for the whole function could include whatever space is needed to throw that type, although I don't know if MSVC does that.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, the answer is compiler-dependent.

A quick experiment with my compiler (`g++ 4.4.3`) reveals that its runtime library first tries to `malloc` memory for the exception and, failing that, attempts to allocate space within a process-wide "emergency buffer" that lives on the data segment. If that doesn't work out, it calls `std::terminate()`.

It would appear that the main purpose of the emergency buffer is to be able to throw `std::bad_alloc` after the process has run out of heap space (in which case the `malloc` call would fail).

The relevant function is [`__cxa_allocate_exception`](http://mosync.googlecode.com/svn/gcc4/trunk/gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_alloc.cc):

```
extern "C" void *
__cxxabiv1::__cxa_allocate_exception(std::size_t thrown_size) throw()
{
  void *ret;

  thrown_size += sizeof (__cxa_refcounted_exception);
  ret = malloc (thrown_size);

  if (! ret)
    {
      __gnu_cxx::__scoped_lock sentry(emergency_mutex);

      bitmask_type used = emergency_used;
      unsigned int which = 0;

      if (thrown_size > EMERGENCY_OBJ_SIZE)
        goto failed;
      while (used & 1)
        {
          used >>= 1;
          if (++which >= EMERGENCY_OBJ_COUNT)
            goto failed;
        }

      emergency_used |= (bitmask_type)1 << which;
      ret = &emergency_buffer[which][0];

    failed:;

      if (!ret)
        std::terminate ();
    }

  // We have an uncaught exception as soon as we allocate memory.  This
  // yields uncaught_exception() true during the copy-constructor that
  // initializes the exception object.  See Issue 475.
  __cxa_eh_globals *globals = __cxa_get_globals ();
  globals->uncaughtExceptions += 1;

  memset (ret, 0, sizeof (__cxa_refcounted_exception));

  return (void *)((char *)ret + sizeof (__cxa_refcounted_exception));
}
```

I don't know how typical this scheme is.

Comment: "in which case the `malloc` call would fail" well, usually, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 22):

From [this page](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html#base-om):

> Storage is needed for exceptions being
> thrown. This storage must persist
> while stack is being unwound, since it
> will be used by the handler, and must
> be thread-safe. **Exception object
> storage will therefore normally be
> allocated in the heap**, although
> **implementations may provide an
> emergency buffer** to support throwing
> bad_alloc exceptions under low memory
> conditions.

Now, this is only the Itanium ABI and I'm looking for details specific to GCC, Clang and MSVC. However, the standard doesn't specify anything and this seems to be the obvious way to implement exception storage, so...

Comment: Still looking for details? Sometimes it'd be nice to be able to accept more than one answer :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this will answer your question, but [**this (How a C++ compiler implements exception handling)**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/exceptionhandler.aspx) is excellent article about the exception handling at all: . I highly recommend it (:

Sorry for the short answer, but the whole information in the article is great, I can't pick and post some info here.

Comment: Search for `excpt_info` in that page, it gives some info how MSVC does it.

Comment: That link really describes how not to do it in a good implementation.  I know some older VC++ used something like this, but I doubt you'll find it in any modern compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard generally specifies how the language behaves but not how the compiler should implement that behavior. I think this question falls into that category. The best way to implement something like this depends on the specifics of the machine -- some processors have lots of general purpose registers, some have very few. A processor might even be built with a special register just for exceptions, in which case the compiler should be free to take advantage of that feature.

Answer (score -2):

Well, it can't be on the stack, since that's going to be unwound, and it can't be on the heap, since that would mean that the system likely couldn't throw `std::bad_alloc`.  Other than that, it's completely up to the implementation: not implementation specified (which must be documented), but unspecified.  (An implementation could use the heap most of the time, as long as it has some sort of emergency back-up that will allow a limited number of exceptions even when there's no more memory.)

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself.

Comment: How?  It presents the constraints on an implementation, which are implicit in the standard.

Comment: One example: "it can't be on the heap" ... "An implementation could use the heap most of the time". In addition, the entire first half of the answer is wrong, as explained in other answers (and, indeed, partially in the second part of yours!).

Comment: The standard requires `std::bad_alloc` to work.  This means that an implementation cannot systematically use the heap.  The standard doesn't allow it.  I'm basing my claims on the standard.

Comment: FSVO of "systematically", that's correct. However, as you state in the second part of your answer, an implementation can indeed use the heap^H^H^H^Hfreestore in conjunction with alternatives.